# Treatment of integers of different size

Tags: c++, integer, uint32, uint, uint8t

A general question about supporting and treatment of multiple different integer sizes and whether they should be treated as independent types (like string vs int) or one a subset of the other. Specifically I'm considering uint8_t and uint32_t.

I want to construct a message object which I shall use to send a message across a network. In the simplest case it will have a header containing the size of the payload, and a payload. I have 3 types of data to send.

1. String data where the header is the length of the string, and the payload is the string.
2. 1 byte integer data, where the header is 1 and the payload is a uint8_t.
3. 4 byte integer data, where the header is 4 and the payload is a uint32_t.

(Actually I also use one bit of the header to flag whether it's an int or a string type, but that's not really important here).

In creating my message object, obviously I treat string as distinct from integer and it has its own constructor to create the raw message. I'm trying to determine what is the best practice for dealing with the different types of integers.

I could:

1. Treat them separately. Having two constructors, one accepting a uint8_t and one accepting a uint32_t.
2. Treat the uint8_t as a subset of the uint32_t and having a one constructor accepting a uint32_t and then testing whether its most significant three bytes are zero.

Ultimately I would like to have support for 1, 2, 4 and 8 byte integers and don't like the idea of the proliferation in constructors I'd get if I took option 1, when I can have one general constructor and test the value of what I'm passed to determine what type it should be. However I want to do the "correct" thing. So my question is ... should uint8_t and uint32_t be treated as separate types, in the same way string and uint8_t would be. Or is it good practice to consider a uint8_t as a subset of a uin32_t?

Comment: Why not use a third party network library? They usually have stream functions such as push_int8 push_int32 etc. Then you can send the members however you want. It doesn't even have to be the same type, if you use an int to store only small values in your object.

Comment: I'd say that the first option is the good way. Types purpose is to carry  information in compile-time; the second option would throw this information away. I'd advise writing a generic template method for integral types.

Comment: Is the message object intended to be strictly a transport mechanism, or is it intended to transmit the type as well? If you make separate constructors for the different integer types you'll get errors, since the integers are implicitly convertible.

Answer (score 0):

As I've said in comments, the first option is better since it uses the type information you have. There is no need in creating different message constructors for `uint8`, `uint32` and others; templates will help you.

Here's an example of a generic message-constructing function, which works for all POD types:

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_pos<T>::value, void>::type>
message create_message (T const & x)
{
    message m;
    m.write(&x, sizeof(T));
    return m;
}
```

(I assume that your `message` type has some method like `write(void*, size_t)`)